# Representing a plugboard in a web interface

Tags: web-app, skeuomorphism

I'm currently making an enigma machine in JavaScript (early working prototype [here](https://c9.io/sam-higton/enigmajs/workspace/hello-world.html)). I've now just reached the stage where I need to implement the plugboard.

Now the plugboard is a set of 26 sockets, one for each letter, that can be patched together with a cable, with the effect of swapping those letters around in the output.  An example of a plugboard is here:

[image: example plugboard]

Each socket can only be connected once. (so if I connect D to E, then neither D nor E can be connected to again).

Now, the problem I have, is that I really don't know the best way to implement this in a user interface. I've thought of making each socket a select box, but I don't think that would be intuitive to use. directly representing plugs and patch cables would look quite messy, and would a nightmare to develop.

So does anybody have any ideas on how to implement such a plugboard in a web interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropdowns (or spinners) would be a fairly obvious choice. Change corresponding pairs together, so that if you link A to D, D gets linked to A.

The implementation problem would then be changing an already-linked D to link to (say) F: you would need to unlink it from A (so you get A↔A) and make a new reciprocal link F↔D. It would be easier to disable D's spinner when it's linked from somewhere else, so that the user would need to explicitly set A↔A before changing D; but that's not as intuitive.

You could use colour to show letters which are linked. (I'd suggest a single colour for "This letter is patched", rather than indicating each pair with a different colour.)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgSBq2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>